# Is there any way to upload files using android cordova app to a shared google drive folder?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-drive-api, cordova-plugins

I am trying to build an android app that takes a file and uploads it to a drive folder which is shared with public. 
I have used file transfer plugin, but it didn't work.

I want to upload files from different devices to one shared drive folder. Is that possible?

If not, is there any other way to collect files to a certain place?

It is not a big project, so I don't want to buy a hosting service and free hosts don't let using scripts to upload files.

Here is my applications code if you are interested:

```js
var app = {

initialize: function(){this.bindEvents();},
bindEvents: function () {document.addEventListener('deviceready',this.onDeviceReady, false)},
onDeviceReady: function () {
  function alert(event){
    console.log(event);
  }

  var Permission = window.plugins.Permission

  var permission = 'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'

  Permission.has(permission, function(results) {
      if (!results[permission]) {
          Permission.request(permission, function(results) {
              console.log(results);
          }, alert)
      }
  }, alert)




var button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
var directory = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + "...";
var ft = new FileTransfer();
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.chunkedMode = false;
options.headers = {
      Connection: "close"
   };


var win = function(result){console.log("Code = " + result.responseCode); console.log(result.response);};
var fail = function(event){console.log(event); };


button1.onclick = function(){
ft.upload(directory, encodeURI("..."), win, fail, options);
}

}//ondeviceready
}//app

app.initialize();
```

Comment: Hello there! I know its been a long time, but did you manage to get it done?

Comment: @RafaeldeCastro Hi, well first of all, I do not recommend using Cordova anymore. Flutter is way more better for mobile programming. But, I did manage to get it done, not with Google Drive, but with a homemade web server (I used Wamp), and collected the files on my pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send your file to a back end, then use Google Oauth and Google Drive SDK to auth and move your file to the folder.

For more info, see [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk)

You can also try a plugin such as [this](https://github.com/JcDenton86/cordova-plugin-jc-googledrive) or [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-xitter-googledrive)

Comment: With this method, users have to sign in with their google drive account right?